# Cleave.js phone input with prefix not working with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have tried the following Cleave.js options

```
{
    phone: true,
    phoneRegionCode: 'DE',
    prefix: '+49'
}
```

But it doesn't work with React as you see in this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/philipplu/pen/ZPeKaL)

However it does work without React as you can see in this [Pen](https://codepen.io/philipplu/pen/KEWmxg)

Is it a bug or am I making anything wrong?

Comment: Is this module imported and installed & linked (if needed) correctly?

Comment: yes everything else works fine

Comment: It kind of works like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/5xzlrm61v4 (setting `phone` to `false` inserts the prefix, I have no idea why it won't work properly)

Comment: I know thats the weird thing. I will report it on GitHub. Thanks